# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: no data found with OJDBC6

Tags: java, oracle

I'm working on a legacy project with Java/Oracle

I have a lot of pl/sql procedures and types. I added new field in one of my type. which is new column in one of the database tables. 
In my java code i have code like this:

```
ARRAY arrayObjects = (ARRAY) datum[0];

 Datum[] dataObjects = arrayObjects.getOracleArray();
```

datum[0] contains Array of my type. But at the second row throws :

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: no data found
>
> ORA-06512: at line 1

The problem is not in the pl/sql I debug it and the procedure return correct data. There is a lot of data so it's not Select/Into problem.

Any ideas why this may happen?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to recreate the synonyms of the types.